# Using command python -m http.server and make server reachable by public ip?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can i use the command:

/`python -m http.server` and make the server reachable through my public ip? I know this is NOT safe, but I just wanna try some things out.

Comment: If it says it's serving on IP 0.0.0.0, then that means it's publicly accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it as you normally do.

You'd connect to it by its external IP address. You might need to setup your router to allow that. Read up on port forwarding, for example.

Comment: Is there some special python command that has to be done or should it work with the exact command that I typed?

Comment: @user2422321, I think not. I can't verify that now, though.

Comment: Thank you! It seems like I only needed to port-forward!